# "Hidden" messages in Motorola messaging?

Tags: applications, sms

**Phone info:**

Motorola

Model: Moto E, 2nd generation

LTE: 4G LTE

Operating system: Android, version 5.1

Let me know if any more info would be helpful.

**Issue**:

My phone's Messaging app (the one that comes with the phone) seems to be "hiding" text conversations sometimes. It'll show how many unread messages I have, (see attached image, the circled number), but I don't see any conversations with unread messages shown. I know there are some conversations missing, I just need a way to un-hide them. As far as I have found, the only way to un-hide these conversations is to search for the conversation by contact, but this only works if you know which contact's conversation was hidden. Any thoughts on how to un-do  this, or what is making the messages hidden?

[image]

**My research:**

I've looked on Android support sites, done Google searches of 'Motorola hiding messages', and all sorts of related searches. Unfortunately I have had trouble finding anything besides suggestions on how to hide messages.

Comment: @beeshyams- thank you for that, I didn't realize that was the unread message count! My problem still exists, unfortunately, as I don't see any messages in bold and I know some messages are hidden, but thank you for clearing that one up!

Comment: @beeshyams I tried taking a backup and was able to find two out of the four messages- I am still going through it though so the other two are likely in there as well. Thank you for all your help and I will keep you updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial answer** (OP may update with findings later)

- From my experience of Moto X Play messenger app - the count corresponds to unread messages.
- OP is unable to identify unread messages. Proposed solution:

  - Use [SMS backup & restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) to take the backup in `xml` format and open it on PC (browser, notepad or any other program) and compare with messages on phone to identify "hidden" messages. [OP has been able to identify two](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/223775/hidden-messages-in-motorola-messaging#comment290620_223775) so far
    and  in the process of identifying other two.
  - Find out what is special about those SMS originators. Guessing, they could be contacts saved on SIM, or social media contacts or Google groups /Hangouts or contacts marked spam, blocked/ unknown contacts for calls, carrier messages or....
  - Once the nature of contacts is identified, take steps to treat them as other contacts whose messages are *not* hidden.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Request you to edit the answer with your findings - it may help others in future