# Moto G8 plus - Android 9 - no support for sms message restore from Google backup - how do I manually access these messages?

Tags: backup, sms

I need to restore a Moto G8 plus running Android 9, turns out according to the carrier the crucial messages app does not support restoring SMS. Can I debug and manually access these messages? If so how?

Comment: [MyPhoneExplorer](https://fjsoft.at/en)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228746

Comment: You can try the app [mentioned here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/224096/131553) to backup and see on PC. To restore you can use one of many SMS apps that are available