# Android 9 Pie where are SMS stored please? What is the path to the SMS database?

Tags: sms, 9.0-pie

Android 9 where are SMS stored please? What is the path?

[image]

Comment: */data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db*

Comment: Here is my current path:  
/moto g(8) plus/Internal shared storage/Android/data

I cannot see anything at the moment with user_de

Comment: Internal storage */storage/emulated/0* is just a view of */data/media/0* - as you can see that is a subdirectory of */data* - for that you need root access

Comment: Right it's a moto G8 plus. Wondering what the easiest way to root is, sorry about this but need help

Comment: rooting requires unlocking bootloader (which performes factory reset)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228744

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @alecxs, the sms are stored in the database: "
/data/user_de/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db" which need root privileges to access it or edit it.

If you don't have root access, you can interact with the table `sms` in this database using ADB:

**list all SMS**

```
adb shell content query --uri content://sms
```

**list SMS from +2121212121**

```
adb shell content query --uri content://sms --projection address:date:date_sent:body --where 'address=+2121212121'
```