# How to restore deleted text messages from an galaxy s9 phone

Tags: sms, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I only touched the one text message I wanted to delete and all of my text messages got deleted from my galaxy S9 phone from the default text message app. I really need to restore those messages because many of them contained data I texted to myself that i need. I was told by reading online that when you first delete the message they go to some kind of cloud that is inactive until enough data comes through to permanently erase them. How do I access those. My phone shows only a back up of messages stopping in June or July but i need all of them including the newest texts I made this past month August as well. What do I do?

Comment: Do any of [these answered questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdata-recovery%5D+sms+answers%3A1) help you out? If not, is your device rooted? Are you using any kind of backup software?

Comment: [sqlite](https://sqliteforensictoolkit.com/how-not-to-examine-sqlite-wal-files) databases do not actually delete data immediately, it is just marked as deleted. unfortunately you can't have access to raw database, your data is lost https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228746